# AVPlayer video currentTime always returning 0

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm trying to get the `currentTime()` on an `AVPlayer` video using an `NSTimer`. Using the following code, I'm always returning `0.0` as the video's current time. What am I doing wrong?

```
    var player: AVPlayer!

    @IBOutlet weak var playerContainer: UIView!

    var t1: Float!
    var t2: Float!
    var currentSecs: Float!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!)

        let playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.playerContainer.frame
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        player?.play()

        t1 = Float(self.player.currentTime().value)
        t2 = Float(self.player.currentTime().timescale)
        currentSecs = t1 / t2

        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(TheaterViewController.timeUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func timeUpdate() {

        print(currentSecs) // Only prints 0.0

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. `t1` and `t2` was only getting set once each in `viewDidLoad`. I moved them both to `updateTime` and it worked. -.-